# jsdoc : reference typedef-ed type from other module

Tags: jsdoc, jsdoc3

Assuming I have a typedef type in a js module

```
// somewhere/foo.js
/**
 * @module
 */ 
/**
 * @typedef Foo
 * @type {object}
 * property {string} bar - some property
 */
```

Is it possible to reference this type in another module, so that in the HTML page generated by jsdoc, the type is displayed as a link to the typedef-ed module ?

I tried variations of this, but nothing seems to work...

```
// somewhere_else/bar.js
/**
 * @module
 */
/**
 * @param {somewhere/foo/Foo} foo - some param
 */
export default function doStuff(foo) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This works for me ...

```
// somewhere/foo.js
/**
 * @module foo
 */
/**
 * @typedef module:foo.Foo
 * @type {object}
 * @property {string} bar - some property
 */
```

and ...

```
// somewhere_else/bar.js
/// <reference path="foo.js" />
/**
 * @module bar
 */
/**
 * @param {module:foo.Foo} foo - some param
 */
function doStuff(foo) {
  //...
};
```

Comment: Fully qualifying the module in the @typedef does work (I personnaly wrote `@typedef {Object} module:foo/Foo` , but that's a matter of taste.) However : 1/ the `/// <reference path="foo.js" />` does not seem required, and I could not find it documented anywhere. 2/ if the module has a long path (like 'somewhere/foo') typing it everywhere is a bit tedious, do you know of any trick to alias it somehow ?

Comment: @phtrivier 1. sorry, reference is just a copy and paste from my test, ignore it. 2. Totally agree with you, a bit tedious; unfortunately "alias" is the way we document (specially with prototypes). In fact it's not that bad, as it looks. I see the benefit of it: developer who uses this method or type would exactly know where is it defined, so it helps not just to create correct documentation, but during development to look for references efficient. Yet another way it to use "@exports", but I didn't discover this option, so cannot comment.

Answer (score 8):

The above answer shows up high in search results so I'm documenting what worked for me in case it helps someone in a similar situation.

I'm using Visual Studio code for a node project with `// @ts-check` on all my modules. Using the above syntax hiccups on the `module:` syntax. Also, the code assistance doesn't work properly. It took me a while but the answer ended up being quite simple

If I have the typedef `myTypedef` in a module `myModule` then in the second module where I require `myModule`
`mm = require(myModule)`
I can use something like
`/** @param {mm.myTypedef} myParamName */`

Answer (score 7):

The `module` syntax is not supported by TypeScript so if you're getting here assuming it to work, I haven't been able to get the solutions above to work.

To get it working with TypeScript use [Import Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#import-types)

For the OP the way I would do it is

```
// foo.d.ts
export type Foo = {
  /**
   * some property
   */
  bar: string,
};
```

Then refer to it in the JS module as

```js
/**
 * @typedef { import("./foo").Foo } Foo
 */

/**
 * @param {Foo} foo - some param
 */
export default function doStuff(foo) {
  ...
}
```

You can verify things are working on an individual file more strictly by adding the following to the beginning of the file.  This will enable typescript checking in Visual Studio code for the specific file to help prepare your move to Typescript in the future.

```
// @ts-check
```

Answer (score 1):

Many libraries export types from their root file, to access those in typedefs, change your import to use the `import * as` format.

For example:

```js
import * as testingLibrary from '@testing-library/react';


/** 
 * @returns {testingLibrary.RenderResult}
 */
export function myCustomRender() { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried both of the above approaches.

Firstly, in the case of `@typedef module:foo.Foo`, VSCode treated the usage of Foo within the same file as `any`. Which I didn't find acceptable.

Secondly, when using ES6 imports the following issue emerges:

```
import foo from 'foo'

/** @param {foo.Foo} a - Error Foo does not exist on foo */
```

On the other hand VSCode recognizes `import { Foo } from 'foo'` **without** even using the JSDoc module syntax:

```
/**
 * @module bar
 */
```

What's more I was also able to reference a property on the imported type, namely:

```
import { Foo } from 'foo'

/** @param {Foo['bar']} bar */
```

*Note*

This project uses Babel and assume compiling code which uses type imports in not feasible without a transpiler.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with [vscode-powertools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ego-digital.vscode-powertools) script which provides access to [vscode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/vscode) module **at runtime** (as opposed to it being available to VSCode at edit time via the local `node_modules`).

If I would try to import the types with the usual jsdoc `import`

```
//@ts-check
/** @typedef {import('c:/Users/USERNAME/.vscode/extensions/ego-digital.vscode-powertools-0.64.0/node_modules/vscode').TextEditor} TextEditor */
```

I would be getting the `File is not a module` error:

```
File 'C:/Users/USERNAME/.vscode/extensions/ego-digital.vscode-powertools-0.64.0/node_modules/vscode/vscode.d.ts' is not a module. ts(2306)
```

So here's the trick I'm using to typecheck that kind of script:

```
//@ts-check
/// <reference types="c:/Users/USERNAME/.vscode/extensions/ego-digital.vscode-powertools-0.64.0/node_modules/vscode" /> 

// Allows us to reference the `vscode` module with jsdoc `@type`
async function vscodeⁱ() {if (1 == 1) return null; return import ('vscode')}

exports.execute = async (args) => {
  // Allows us to reference the `vscode` module with jsdoc `@type`
  const vscode = await vscodeⁱ()

  /** @type {vscode} */
  const vs = args.require ('vscode')

  // NB: The following code is fully typed in VSCode
  const windowᵛ = vs.window
  const editorᵛ = windowᵛ.activeTextEditor
  const start = editorᵛ.selection.start
}
```