# How to document an object with only primitive values?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, jsdoc

I would like to document objects that cannot have objects as values using JSDoc.

Example allowed:

```
{
  position: 'ground',
  age: 0,
  alive: false
}
```

Example disallowed:

```
{
  data: [/* ... */]
  people: {/* ... */}
}
```

Is there any way to do the above?
It could be done for example in an [`@type`](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a custom type using union with @typedef

```
@typedef {(number|string|boolean|...)} YourType
```

Then refering to this type in your object documentation

Comment: It's long and cumbersome but welp, if it works ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Ah and what about something like `Object.<string, number|string|boolean>`?

Comment: @PaulStenne Yes, that works as well. Which one is better dependents on your actual need. If that's the only object that require this type and you are sure there will be no non-primitive properties added in the future, I will recommend you do `Object.<string, number|string|boolean|...>`

Comment: I thought it is possible to reuse `@typedef` in other modules, but [reading this issue](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/1537) discourage me. So is it possible to be reused?

Comment: @JordanEnev I found something that may be helpful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42829250/jsdoc-reference-typedef-ed-type-from-other-module